# customtkinter - create frame with other class than the main frame but then assign it to the main frame

Tags: python, class, tkinter, inheritance, customtkinter

i am trying to create parts of my customtkinter-app in other classes so i can then assign them to the App class. But i must do something wrong. As you can see the goal is to place the labeltext from "self.label" to the middle of the frame "self.frame_rot"
Please check my code:

---

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter as ctk


class Frame1(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        
        self.frame_rot = ctk.CTkFrame(master, height = 100, width = 100, fg_color = 'red').grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.frame_rot, text = 'hallo').place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = 'center')
        
        
class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.geometry('500x500')
        self.title('TestApp')
        
        self.frame = Frame1(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I just dont know what to do from here on!!

[image]

Comment: Actually `self.frame_rot` is None as it is the result of `.grid(...)`, so the label will be put inside root window instead.

Comment: Where is tkinter.tK()?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter as ctk

        
class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.geometry('500x500')
        self.title('TestApp')
        
        self.frame = Frame1(self)

class Frame1(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        #if you remove this, the "red block" will stick to the upper left corner
        master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.frame_rot = ctk.CTkFrame(master=master, fg_color='red')
        self.frame_rot.grid(row=0, column=0)

        #sticky "ns" will centralize the label vertically
        self.label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_rot, text='hallo', height=130)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```